# applying theme in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, themes, dynamic

Here i want to set theme for a master page but i don't know how to do it so please tell me some solution .
all the i want to do from code behind.
thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx)

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Request.QueryString["theme"])
    {
        case "Blue":
            Page.Theme = "BlueTheme";
            break;
        case "Pink":
            Page.Theme = "PinkTheme";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the `Page_PreInit` method. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx) for more details.

You can set the theme by setting the [`Page.Theme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.theme.aspx) property. For example, `Page.Theme = "MyTheme"`.

Comment: ya that i know but how can i set it ?

Comment: like this  this.Page.Theme = "collection";  "

Answer (score 0):

vb

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit

        Page.Theme = "ThemeName"

End Sub
```

c#

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Theme = "ThemeName";
}
```